# How to modify the group spacing of X axis in Seaborn distplot

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2kpk.png)
I drew a frequency distribution histogram, but I don't know how to modify its group spacing
Is there any way to change 0-100 of the X axis into 0-50, 50-100, and so on
I want to have such a coordinate axis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojCqC.png)

```py
    
def norm_comparision_plot(data,title, figsize=(14,6), color="#099DD9",ax=None, surround=True, grid=True):

 plt.figure(figsize=figsize) 

 sns.distplot(data,hist=True,fit=norm,color=color,kde_kws={"color": color, "lw": 3}, ax=ax)
 (mu, sigma) = norm.fit(data)

 set(xlim=(0,30),ylim=(0,100)))

 plt.legend([title+'', ' ($\mu=$ {:.2f} and $\sigma=$ {:.2f} )'.format(mu, sigma)], loc='best')
 plt.ylabel('')
 plt.title(title+"")

 if surround == True:
  sns.despine(trim=True, left=True, offset=10)
 if grid == True:
  plt.grid(True) 
 plt.show()
```

Comment: can you add your code to the post ?

Comment: sns.distplot(data,hist=True,fit=norm,color=color,kde_kws={"color": color, "lw": 3}, ax=ax)

Comment: I need to see more of your code in order to help you, can you edit your post and add all the lines in charge of printing this graph?

Comment: def norm_comparision_plot(data,title, figsize=(14,6), color="#099DD9",ax=None, surround=True, grid=True):

 plt.figure(figsize=figsize) 

 sns.distplot(data,hist=True,fit=norm,color=color,kde_kws={"color": color, "lw": 3}, ax=ax)
 (mu, sigma) = norm.fit(data)

 set(xlim=(0,30),ylim=(0,100)))

 plt.legend([title+'', ' ($\mu=$ {:.2f} and $\sigma=$ {:.2f} )'.format(mu, sigma)], loc='best')
 plt.ylabel('')
 plt.title(title+"")

 if surround == True:
  sns.despine(trim=True, left=True, offset=10)
 if grid == True:
  plt.grid(True) 
 plt.show()

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is all my code, but I don't understand why its format is not quite right after it is released

Comment: try adding it to the pos itself and not in the comments,
also after adding it to the post , select all of your code and press Ctrl+k to make it look like code :)

Comment: def norm_comparision_plot(data,title, figsize=(14,6), color="#099DD9",ax=None, surround=True, grid=True):

 plt.figure(figsize=figsize) 

 sns.distplot(data,hist=True,fit=norm,color=color,kde_kws={"color": color, "lw": 3}, ax=ax)
 (mu, sigma) = norm.fit(data)

 set(xlim=(0,30),ylim=(0,100)))

 plt.legend([title+'', ' ($\mu=$ {:.2f} and $\sigma=$ {:.2f} )'.format(mu, sigma)], loc='best')
 plt.ylabel('')
 plt.title(title+"")

 if surround == True:
  sns.despine(trim=True, left=True, offset=10)
 if grid == True:
  plt.grid(True) 
 plt.show()

Answer (score 0):

you didn't post enough of your code yet so I am not sure how accurate I could be here,
but I am guessing that at some point in your code you are calling `plt.subplot`

```
__, ax = plt.subplots(......)
```

in that case, you need to add the line:

```
ax.set(xlim=(0, 100))
```

for your graph to be limited between 0 to 100

hope I could help,
if you need any clarifications please leave here a comment and i will help you

and if this comment helped you please consider marking it as the answer :)